# z3 c++ api modulo operation with integer

Tags: c++, z3, modulo

Is there a way to do a modulo operation with z3 c++ api with integers?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var = context->int_const("foo");
var = var + 1; 
expr = var % 5;
```

It seems there is only a modulo operation for bitvectors?

Am I missing something?

Best
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

There are two operations, depending on what semantics you expect for negative numbers. They are exposed as "mod" and "rem". The semantics is documented on http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-Ints.shtml for arithmetical operations.

```
    /* \brief mod operator */
    friend expr mod(expr const& a, expr const& b);
    friend expr mod(expr const& a, int b);
    friend expr mod(int a, expr const& b);

    /* \brief rem operator */
    friend expr rem(expr const& a, expr const& b);
    friend expr rem(expr const& a, int b);
    friend expr rem(int a, expr const& b);
```

Comment: Where can I find those methods? There is only z3::urem and z3::srem which both operate on bitvectors.